# How to change metrics in plot_function()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

can anyone tell me how to change the plot_model() function to show me the mean and standard deviation? I have looked up the documentation but I don't get it.

Thank you very much in advance!

[Here the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0fbP.png)

```
# visual inspection of data 
fit<-Focus_full
# Plot model
plot_Focus <- plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("Condition", "Group"))+  #geom_line(size = 1) 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, NA),ylim = c(0,5), clip = "off") + theme_tq() +scale_colour_tq() + scale_fill_tq(light) + 
  labs(
    title = "",
    y = "",
    x = "") +  
   ggplot2::labs(colour = "Group") + scale_color_manual(values=c('Red','Black'))
plot_Focus<- plot_Focus + theme_apa()  
plot_Focus
```

Comment: To which package does `plot_model` belong to?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Be sure to explicitly list all the non-base R package you are using.

Comment: It seems like `plot_model` belongs to `sjPlot`, please add its tag to your post. Plus, you can provide sample data using `dput`.

Comment: Under its [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.8.11/topics/plot_model) look at the `bpe` argument as it does mention `mean`.